# Opening links as a new tab

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

On J.SE (and I'm guessing on all SE sites) when you click on a link, it opens in your current window. Wouldn't it be more convenient if it opens as a new tab or window? (Is the problem on my end/with my computer?) Is there any way to get this changed?

Comment: You can do that through your browser, but if the site were to do that those who don't want it would not be able to *not* do it.

Comment: Related MSO question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35677/have-all-links-open-in-a-new-tab

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this will not be changed. Many users don't want every link they click in a new tab or window. Those who do can set that preference in their browser (for some browsers); and if someone wants a specific click to open a link in a new tab/window then he can (again, in some browsers) right- (or command-) click the link and select that option, or middle-click the link.

Comment: fair enough. Is there no way to do it only for citations though or something?

Comment: Or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and click the link.

Comment: Or use the middle mouse button

Comment: @Vram, seemingly the CSS `.post-text a{target-new:tab}` (in a personal stylesheet) will work, but only in browsers that support that part of CSS3 (and I don't know whether *any* do yet). But you can try it.